# Error al instalar el plugin Mercadopago 1.6 con PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: mercadopago, prestashop

Estoy teniendo un problema al instalar Mercadopago en prestashop 1.6
Lo estoy instalando en un servidor local (con Apache, PHP, y MySQL).

La tienda (prestashop) está funcionando bien, pero al querer instalar el módulo Mercado Pago, me sale un siguiente error. (parece que se instala y el error viene al configurar, puesto que luego me aparece como instalado).

Al querer configurar me aparece lo siguiente:

> [PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file :C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\modules\mercadopago\includes\MPRestCli.php:
>   Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can not call the API, status code 0.' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\modules\mercadopago\includes\MPRestCli.php:151 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\modules\mercadopago\includes\MPRestCli.php(174): MPRestCli::exec('GET', '/v1/payment_met...', NULL, 'application/jso...', 'https://api.mer...') #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\modules\mercadopago\includes\MPApi.php(285): MPRestCli::get('/v1/payment_met...') #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\modules\mercadopago\mercadopago.php(994): MPApi->getOfflinePaymentMethods() #3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\controllers\admin\AdminModulesController.php(867): MercadoPago->getContent() #4 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\controllers\admin\AdminModulesController.php(1116): AdminModulesControllerCore->postProcessCallback() #5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\classes\controller\Controller.php(178): AdminModulesControllerCore->postProcess() #6 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\classes\Dispatcher.php(367): ControllerCore->run() #7 C:\Apache24\htdocs\shop\admin720vbqjik\index.php

Aclaro que tengo cUrl habilitado y un certificado digital descargado de https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html (cacert.pem)

Comment: El certificado, se ha configurado correctamente en el **php.ini**? **Ejm:** [curl] curl.cainfo=c:\php\certificado\cacert.pem